# Check if OpenCV is compiled with TBB

Tags: linux, opencv, tbb

How can I check if the OpenCV libraries installed on my Linux machine are compiled against TBB libraries or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Print the shared library dependencies of *libopencv_core* using **ldd**:

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
```

And you should see TBB on the list.

If you were on Mac OS X the equivalent is **otool -L**, and on my system it outputs:

```
/Users/karlphillip/installers/OpenCV-2.4.2/build/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.2)
libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

So according to the output above, my OpenCV installation was built to support TBB. ;D

Comment: Would it be possible to perform this check with CMake without relying on ldd ?

Comment: Yes. After you execute cmake it prints a list of the features that it supports and that will be compiled.

Comment: So, when in your own project you use FindPackage(OpenCV), you are able to search like OpenCV_HAS_TBB ?

Comment: Something like that. Download OpenCV sources and check the file `OpenCVDetectTBB.cmake`.

Comment: On Mac the command is `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib`

Comment: I'd personally like to find out how to do this within CMake. Running ldd or whatever is not directly supported by build systems and is not portable.