# How to check if OpenCV was compiled with TBB, CUDA or Qt support?

Tags: windows, opencv

How can I find out whether OpenCV library was compiled with TBB or CUDA or QT on Windows 7 machine? Should I use dependency walker, and if so, how? Or is there another way to find out?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12464545/1758762

Comment: @duDE I saw that, but it is for Linux. Also I was wandering if there is another way other way to check.

Answer (score 14):

You can know it by opening a python3 REPL in cmdline:

```
python3
```

Then importing opencv:

```
import cv2
```

Then printing build information:

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

And look for CUDA and related GPU information.

Comment: what about TBB or Qt support?

Comment: For TBB please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457885/check-if-opencv-is-compiled-with-tbb

Comment: This answer refers to linux op is asking about windows

Answer (score 4):

following up on dpetrini's answer, You can add whatever support to want to regex search in this to pretty-fy the outputs, instead of searching for it in the build-info outputs.

```py
import cv2
import re

cv_info = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', ci.strip()) for ci in cv2.getBuildInformation().strip().split('\n') 
               if len(ci) > 0 and re.search(r'(nvidia*:?)|(cuda*:)|(cudnn*:)', ci.lower()) is not None]
print(cv_info)
```

```sh
['NVIDIA CUDA: YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)', 'NVIDIA GPU arch: 75', 'NVIDIA PTX archs:', 'cuDNN: YES (ver 7.6.5)']
```

Answer (score 2):

If OpenCV is compiled with CUDA capability, it will return non-zero for getCudaEnabledDeviceCount function (make sure you have CUDA installed). Another very simple way is to try using a GPU function in OpenCV and use try-catch. If an exception is thrown, you haven't compiled it with CUDA.

Comment: what about TBB or Qt support?

Answer (score 1):

For CUDA support you can check gpu module size. If OpenCV is compiled without CUDA support, opencv_gpu.dll will have small size (< 1 MB), it will be a dummy package. The real size of gpu module built with CUDA support is ~ 70 MB for one compute capability.

Comment: that's more like a hack, i'm looking for something more reliable

Answer (score 0):

```
bool _cudaSupported  = false;

...
// Obtain information from the OpenCV compilation
// Here is a lot of information.
const cv::String str = cv::getBuildInformation();

// Parse looking for "Use Cuda" or the option you are looking for.
std::istringstream strStream(str);

std::string line;
while (std::getline(strStream, line))
{
    // Enable this to see all the options. (Remember to remove the break)
    //std::cout << line << std::endl;

    if(line.find("Use Cuda") != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Trim from elft.
        line.erase(line.begin(), std::find_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))));

        // Trim from right.
        line.erase(line.begin(), std::find_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))));

        // Convert to lowercase may not be necessary.
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (line.find("yes") != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "USE CUDA = YES" << std::endl;
            _cudaSupported = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```