# The output image of opencv in pycharm has white boarders at around the image

Tags: opencv

I am trying to show a simple image output in pycharm using opencv but the output always contains white boarders around the image and I am not sure how to remove those boarders. I am using linux mint.[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjFiF.png)  I got as output, as I mentioned it has white boarders around the image.

I used the following code

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(path)

cv2.imshow("Output",img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: I think they result from using **Qt** for the display. You can get your build configuration and check `GUI` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607376/2836621

Comment: Thanks for helping out, GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO            ,my build information shows this,so what should in this

Comment: I don't know of any way to switch the GUI at run-time, I think you have to compile and build with the one you want. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you consider pycharm has something to do with the display? If you execute the script outside pycharm is different for example?

Comment: No it still produces the same output